# Who were the sons of Varuna killed by Ravana?

Tags: ramayana, ravana, war, varuna

In [Yuddha Kanda, Chapter 7](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga7/yuddha_7_frame.htm), when the ministers are eulogising Ravana about his qualities, they say that the four sons of Varuna were killed (defeated?) by Ravana.

> śūrāḥ ca balavantaḥ ca varuṇasya sutā raṇe | 
> nirjitās te mahābāga
>   catur vidha bala anugāḥ || 6-7-12
>
> Oh, illustrious king! Varuna's sons, valiant strong and who were
>   followed by an army having four limbs (viz. elephants, chariots,
>   cavalry and infantry) were defeated by you in a battle.

Who are those sons and why were they killed by Ravana?

Comment: The full story is narrated in [Uttarakanda Ch. 23](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-23) but the sons' actual names are not mentioned.